# How can I hide and unhide buttons with the same UIButton?

Tags: uibutton, ibaction

I have to hide some buttons when I tap a button, and unhide them when I touch the button again.
This is what I have:

```
- (IBAction)hideButtons {
    backbutton.hidden = YES; 
    nextbutton.hidden = YES;
    resetbutton.hidden = YES;
}
```

and

```
- (IBAction)showButtons {
    backbutton.hidden = NO; 
    nextbutton.hidden = NO;
    resetbutton.hidden = NO;
}
```

How can I do this with one button? At first the buttons should be unhidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use this:
(Works if all buttons are in the same state first):

```
backbutton.hidden=!backbutton.hidden; 
nextbutton.hidden=!nextbutton.hidden;
resetbutton.hidden=!resetbutton.hidden;
```

Hope this helps